# Change the background-image from the Style Sheet using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to create a javascript + jquery function to change the background-image from my css file.

If I try to change the value of `background-color` it works, but not with `background-image`.

```
function randomWallpaper()
{
     var wallpapersList = ["1.jpg","9.jpg","3.jpg", "82.jpg"];
     var newWallpaper = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+0;
     console.log(newWallpaper); //outputs the index
     changeBackground(wallpapersList, newWallpaper);
 }

function changeBackground(wallpapersList, newWallpaper) 
{
     $("body").css("background-image", wallpapersList[newWallpaper]);
}

setInterval(function()
{
     randomWallpaper();
},2500)
```

**CSS**

```
body 
{
    background-image: url('41.jpeg');
}
```

Could anyone help me to understand where I am wrong and why this piece of code does not work?
I am trying to learn js

Comment: It's not just a Url.... `url('41.jpeg');` <- wrap it with `url()`

Comment: 1. function name is randomWallpaper but you are calling randomWalpaper

Comment: That was a typo here when I was writing it... The code is working on the site. Thanks for letting me know that here was wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type `url()` too.

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url(" + wallpapersList[newWallpaper] + ")" )
```

(or with ES6 string interpolation syntax :)

```
$("body").css("background-image", `url( ${wallpapersList[newWallpaper]} )` )
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed put, it's the `url()` bit. Some room for improvement:

```
function randomWallpaper()
{
    // In JS we mostly talk about arrays rather than lists
    const wallpapersArray = ["1.jpg","9.jpg","3.jpg", "82.jpg"];
    // Instead of hard-coding 5, use the length of the array (+1)
    const newIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (wallpapersArray.length+1));
    // Don't pass the whole array, just pass the URL we need
    changeBackground(wallpapersArray[newIndex]);
 }

function changeBackground(newWallpaperUrl) 
{
    $("body").css("background-image", "url('"+newWallpaperUrl+"')");
}

setInterval(function()
{
    // You forgot an l here
    randomWallpaper();
}, 2500);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the extra things I didnt see.